# How to create a Futoshiki GUI using JPanel in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on my GUI for a Futoshiki game. I've managed to display the board with the number squares. However, I'd like to know how I would implement the relational squares that have the greater and less than symbols. Would really appreciate the help.

This what my GUI currently looks like now.

[image]

Basically something resembling the picture below.[image]

Here is my code...

```
public FutoshikiGUI()
{
    int row, col;
    grid  = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,5));
    cells = new PanelCell[5+1][5+1];
 
    for (row=1; row<=5; row++) 
    {
      for (col=1; col<=5; col++) 
      {
        cells[row][col] = new PanelCell(this,row,col);
        grid.add(cells[row][col]);
      }
    }
       
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(grid, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

public PanelCell(FutoshikiGUI p,  int r, int c)
{
    if (p == null)
     throw new FutoshikiException("cannot have null panel");
    if ((r<1) || (r>5))
      throw new FutoshikiException("invalid row (" + r + ")");
    if ((c<1) || (c>5))
      throw new FutoshikiException("invalid col (" + c + ")");
      
    panel = p;
    row   = r;
    col   = c;
        
    setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
    setForeground(Color.black);
    setFont(font);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks it's hard to explain my question without confusing people.

Comment: Lol so how do you expect an answer then? We might not all speak the same language but we all code in the same language. @AndrewThompson mentioned giving us the shortest possible fully compilable code to reproduce your issue. You could then show us the lines of code or method where you are having problems and we can attempt to help you out by running your code and figuring it out.

Comment: I have simpflifed the code as much as I can, I've added a screenshot of the issue I am having if that helps. Hopefully the information is suffcient if not I can edit my post to fit with the feedback @AndrewThompson has provided.

Comment: @BSK Use a GridLayout with `4+5=9` columns/rows for the digits and the greater/smaller symbols.

Comment: How would I implement that @Progman? by changing this `grid  = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,5));`

Comment: @BSK Yes, use `GridLayout(9, 9)` and place the digits and greater/smaller symbols in the same grid.

Comment: @Progman I've changed the GridLayout to 9,9, but I need a way to add the greater/smaller symbols squares like in the image but I'm sure how to do this. How would I implement this?

Comment: @Abra Yes please that would be very helpful.

Comment: You're going to keep running into problems.  Take a step back, and create a game model using plain Java classes to hold a logical model of the game.  Once you have the logical model, your Swing GUI view can simply display the contents of your logical game model.  Your controller classes (ActionListeners) will modify the logical game model and update / repaint the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested. The below code simply displays your desired Futoshiki puzzle [board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsZQs.png).

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Futoshiki implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createGrid() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 9));
        // First row
        panel.add(new JButton("4"));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton("2"));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("\u25B6", Color.white, Color.gray));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        // Second row
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        // Third row
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("\u25B6", Color.white, Color.gray));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        // Fourth row
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("\u25B2", Color.white, Color.gray));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("\u25B2", Color.white, Color.gray));
        // Fifth row
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        // Sixth row
        panel.add(createColorButton("\u25B2", Color.white, Color.gray));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        // Seventh row
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("\u25C0", Color.white, Color.gray));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("\u25B6", Color.white, Color.gray));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        // Eighth row
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("\u25BC", Color.white, Color.gray));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.darkGray, null));
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        // Last row
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(createColorButton("", Color.white, null));
        panel.add(new JButton());
        return panel;
    }

    private JButton createColorButton(String text, Color bg, Color fg) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        if (bg != null) {
            button.setBackground(bg);
        }
        if (fg != null) {
            button.setForeground(fg);
        }
        return button;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Futoshiki");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createGrid(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Futoshiki());
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Futoshiki puzzle board]

Comment: Thanks that's brilliant, how would I go about adding keyListner for the number and greater and less rthan squares? I have created the logic for the number input.
```
```

Comment: @BSK I specifically asked if all you want is code that displays the board. Now that you have that, if you want to ask another question, then post another question.

Comment: Sure I will ask a new question is it ok to send the link to new the question? @Abra