# Need help moving the buttons using JPanel GridLayout in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I want to move my buttons for my GUI game which is a 9x9 grid so the buttons appear as the image below. I have tried hard but can not figure it out.

The current issue I am having.

[image]

What I want it to look like.

[image]

```
public FutoshikiGUI()
{        
    grid  = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,9));
    cells = new PanelCell[5+1][5+1];     
    
    for (int row=1; row<=5; row++) 
    {
        for (int col=1; col<=5; col++)
        {
            // number input
            cells[row][col] = new PanelCell(this,row,col);
            grid.add(cells[row][col]); 
            if(col < 5)
            {
               // relation input 
              JButton button = new JButton("");
              button.setBackground(Color.white);
              button.setOpaque(true);
              button.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
              grid.add(button);
            }      
        }
    }
   
    for (int row=1; row<=4; row++) 
    {
        for (int col=1; col<=5; col++)
        {
            // relation input
            JButton btn = new JButton("");
            btn.setBackground(Color.white);
            btn.setOpaque(true);
            btn.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            grid.add(btn);
            if(col < 5)
            { 
              // blank input 
              JButton button = new JButton("");
              button.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
              button.setOpaque(true);
              button.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
              grid.add(button);
            }      
        }
    }
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(grid, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

Comment: What was wrong with @Abre's answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495651/how-to-create-a-futoshiki-gui-using-jpanel-in-java)?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I need it to work with my  `PanelCell` class because this has a KeyListener that allows you to enter a number between 1 and 5. Also the instance variable `cells` is also used in my clear method which starts a new a game. So I wouldn't want to remove the functionality I've already created for the game.

Comment: *I need it to work with my PanelCell class* - so then modify the approach to work with your PanelCell class. We have no idea what the PanelCell class is so how do you expect us to tell you how to use it? All we can do it provide the approach for laying out the components based on your picture, which was done in your last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `PanelCell` objects are the "blue" cells, while the "white" cells are buttons with the `white` background and the gray cells are buttons with the `darkGray` background color.

First of all (to make your code easier to maintain) I suggest you create a simple "factory method" to create your buttons:

```
public static JButton createButton(Color background) {
    JButton button = new JButton("");
    button.setBackground(background);
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    return button;
}
```

This method contains redundant code that you where repeating three times (but you only change the background color). So it is easier to put it in a method and pass the background color as a parameter.

Now your code would look like this (I shortened the formatting):

```
for (int row=1; row<=5; row++){
    for (int col=1; col<=5; col++){
        cells[row][col] = new PanelCell(this,row,col);
        grid.add(cells[row][col]); 
        if(col < 5){
          grid.add(createButton(Color.white));  // I just replaced your code with the method call to create the button instance
        }      
    }
}

for (int row=1; row<=4; row++) {
    for (int col=1; col<=5; col++){
        grid.add(createButton(Color.white));
        if(col < 5){ 
          grid.add(createButton(Color.darkGray));
        }      
    }
}
```

Now you have an array of `PanelCell`s that can contain 6 rows and 6 columns. Your `for` loops however start at index `1`, which means that actually your array will have no cells in the first row. 
Always start `for` loops with index 0 and let them finish at the "length" of the array - then those errors don't happen anymore.

```
cells = new PanelCell[5][5];  // in your image I only see 5 "blue" cells in a row and 5 columns in each row

for(int row=0; row<cells.length; row++){   // you already initialised the array to have 5 rows
   for(int col=0; col<cells[row].length; col++){  // now you can be sure that all cells are iterated over once (each row and each column)
     // ...
   }
 }
```

So you iterate over 5 rows and 5 columns each time. You add a new `PanelCell` to your grid and (for the first 4 columns) you add a white button.
**And here is the problem**
After creating your first 25 cells, you iterate again over 4 rows and 5 columns and add white and gray buttons. So in the end your grid contains 5 rows with blue and white buttons and 4 rows with gray and white buttons.

So you have to think of a way to fill your grid in the right order. Here is an example on how you can do that without maintaining a cell array :

```
for(row=0; row<9; row++){     // your grid should contain 9 rows 
   for(col=0; col<9; col++){  // and 9 columns in each row
      if(row%2==0){           // your blue buttons are only in "even" rows (0,2,4,6,8)
         if(col%2==0){        // in even rows your blue buttons are only in even columns
            grid.add(new PanelCell(...));  // create your PanelCell
         }else{
            grid.add(createButton(Color.white)); // in "uneven" columns you add a white button)
         }
      }else{                  // in uneven rows you have white buttons in even columns and gray buttons in uneven columns
          if(col%2==0){        
            grid.add(createButton(Color.white));  // create a white button
         }else{
            grid.add(createButton(Color.darkGray)); // create a gray button
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

And now this should work. The code above is only an example and should fill your "grid" correctly, however it does not take into account how to handle your "cell" array or create the `PanelCell` instances.

Comment: It display nicely, I am just struggling to get the PanelCell class to work as I get an error `Index 6 out of bounds for length 5`. For the first if statement on your last example I added `cells[row][col] = new PanelCell(this,row,col); grid.add(cells[row][col]); ` but does't seem to assign the numbers into the cell  @GameDroids

Comment: You are now looping over 9 rows (0-8) and 9 columns for each row (also 0-8), so when it wants to add a new cell at row 6 it fails because the array is initialised with only 5 rows. It now depends on what is best for you: Either you store all cells from the grid in your grid array (nice but unnecessary) or you make sure your `cell` array is filled in the correct indices: `cells[row/2][col/2]= new PanelCell(...)` it will "map" your `grid` index to your `cell` index for each PanelCell

Comment: Ok thanks I've also added this for my clear method aswell. I am having another issue when I can assign a number to all the number cells as I get an error ` Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" FutoshikiException: invalid row (0)` but I think this will need to be a new question @GameDroids